# Submit specific form inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to submit a form like below

```
 {foreach from=$myInfo item=list}
  <tr>  
      <td>    
          <form id="formq" method="post" action="{eval var=$rootPath}/devt/index?request=getme">

  <input type="text" name="taskida" value="{$list.pa_id}" >
<input type="button" onclick="addFunction();" value="Add Task">
</form></td></tr>{/foreach}
```

How will I submit only the `pa_id`which I click submit and not the entire list.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function addFunction() {
 document.getElementById('formq').submit();
```

}

Comment: It look like you have multiple forms ???

Comment: @HaiderAli  yes but even if I'm using variable as form name,I'm stuck with the JavaScript part

Comment: Are you using PHP? for this?

Comment: I'm using php,this is a view script

Comment: @AdrianVeidt use unique form id for each form ... and where is your submit button ????

Comment: @HaiderAli I've edited the question.okay but to call that id from javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You can assign one id to only one element. You can NOT use single ID for mutliple elements on the same page.

For example in the loop you have multiple forms after execution of loop with the same id **formq**. That is wrong. You have to use unique ID for each element.

So try your code in something like this:

**HTML/PHP**

```
 {foreach from=$myInfo item=list}

  <tr>  
  <td>    
      <form id="formq_{$list.pa_id}" post" action="{eval var=$rootPath}/devt/index?request=getme">

 <input type="text" name="taskida" value="{$list.pa_id}" >
 <input type="button" onclick="addFunction({$list.pa_id});" value="Add Task">
 </form></td></tr>
 {/foreach}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function addFunction(id) {
document.getElementById('formq'+id).submit();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it
  using `$list.pa_id` as form id and passing it to script

`<input type="button" onclick="addFunction($list.pa_id);" value="Add Task">`

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function addFunction(id) {
 document.getElementById(id).submit();`